# In React SharePoint WebPart what are the differences between using 'html-react-parser' & using 'dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss' to securely show HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sharepoint

I am trying to build a React.js SharePoint modern web part, which have the following capabilities:-

1. Inside the Web Part settings page >> there are 2 fields named as "Who We Are" & "Our Value" which allow the user to enter HTML.
2. The web part will render 2 buttons "Who We Are" & "Our Value" >> and when the user clicks on any button >> a Popup will be shown with the entered HTML code in step-1

Something as follow:-

[image]

But to be able to render HTML code as Rich-Text inside my Web Part, i have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute inside the .tsx file. as follow:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal2 = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}>
   </p>

        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

And to secure the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, **i did the following steps**:-

1- Inside my Node.Js CMD >> i run this command inside my project directory:-

```
npm install dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss
```

2- Then inside my above `.tsx` i made the following modifications:-

- I added this import `import { sanitize } from 'dompurify';`
- An I replaced this unsafe code `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}></p>` with this `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(myprops.OurValue) }} />`

**So I have the following question:-**

1. Now my approach (of using `sanitize(myprops.OurValue)` will/should securely render HTML as Rich-Text inside the popup since i am using the `sanitize` function which is part of the `dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss`. but i read another approach which mentioned that to securely render HTML as Rich-Text inside the popup, we can use the `html-react-parser` package as follow `{parse(myprops.OurValue)}`. So what are the differences between using 'html-react-parser' & using 'dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss' to securely render an HTML code as Rich-Text inside the React web part's popup?

*Here is my Full web part code:-*

inside the MyModalPopupWebPart.ts:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'MyModalPopupWebPartStrings';
import MyModalPopup from './components/MyModalPopup';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './components/IMyModalPopupProps';

export interface IMyModalPopupWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  WhoWeAre: string;
  OurValue:string;
}

export default class MyModalPopupWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyModalPopupWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> = React.createElement(
      MyModalPopup,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        WhoWeAre: this.properties.WhoWeAre,
        OurValue: this.properties.OurValue
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('WhoWeAre', {
                  label: "who We Are",
    multiline: true
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('OurValue', {
                  label: "Our value"
                }), PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: "Description",
    multiline: true
                }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

inside the MyModalPopup.tsx:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [`html-react-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) returns ReactJs object, and its return type is like `React.createElement` or like type of called JSX.

Using [`DOMPurify.sanitize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) will return safe pure HTML elements which those are different to the object that `html-react-parser` returns. the [`risxss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-risxss) ESLint plugin will force you to use sanitizing with any kind of sanitize function or library, that I left an answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69940844/6877799) to how to Sanitize your *string HTML*.

**Eventually**, using sanitizing is better because is the `html-react-parser` will convert your *string HTML* to ReactJs object with some tiny changes that would be dangerous because it is possible to have some script of *string HTML* in the project and it maybe will be harmful it just remove the `onclick` or `onload`, etc, from HTML tags but sanitizing will remove all possible harmful tags. also sanitizing will receive configuration, which means you can have your own *options* for sanitizing.

Comment: ok thanks for the useful reply.. but if i use the `sanitize(html)` without passing any options, will it also secure the html? or if i am not passing any option then the `sanitize` will not have any effect?

Comment: Dear @johnGu, passing option to `sanitize` function is optional, it is not mandatory, actually the sanitize function has its own defaultOptions and it is very strict, you can test it. it purges the _string HTML_. no worries, you know bro, I like to have my own options anywhere,  to exactly be sure get what I want. I read all the options [here](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html#default-options)

Comment: so the default options should be secure enough unless we have stricter requirements?

Comment: The default options are enough secure, and so strict, by my opinion, our custom options can make it more stricter or even less. I like less stricter for some type of projects. but it seems you like hare strict ones.